# How Should I use SCM?

Tags: git, version-control

After reading Getting Good With Git, I've learnt how to use Git, but not how I should implement it while developing. eg. When should I branch/merge, what are tags and what should I do with them?

-- Currently I'm a solo dev of this project.

Comment: its all up to you, really, you can use it to sync code with your team mates, or if you are developing alone, you can use it like a backup system, and more.
i myself use it like an 'undo machine' when im working on my personal projects,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're the sole developer and you're just doing development, simply work on the `master` branch.

If you're making regular releases, tag your releases with `git tag -a`. With a tag, it's easy to go back and make a branch from that point if you need to fix something in production.

If you're working on experimental new features that might take a while to get right, consider making branches for your work. With separate branches you can easily have multiple ideas in development at once.

For an example of a complex development environment, have a look at [A successful Git branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/). If you're disciplined, that model is doable even for single-developer projects. But it's not required at all.

Comment: Ah this looks perfect, and the link. Thank you so much for this info.